# Zend framework 2 filters

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

When I use `InputFilter` required is not considered in `int filters`

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name'     => 'id',
    'required' => true,
    'filters'  => array(
        array('name' => 'Int'),
    ),
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `allowEmpty` attribute in order to force your InputFilter component to reject empty values.

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name'     => 'id',
    'required' => true,
    'allowEmpty' => false, // <--- Look ma
    'filters'  => array(
        array('name' => 'Int'),
    ),
)));
```

Comment: Can you add the usage of the InputFilter into the question? It should work.

Comment: I use this => use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;     
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;                 
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;   
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;  
use Zend\Validator\NotEmpty;   
use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\EmailAddress;
use Zend\Validator\Between;

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use the `Int` **InputFilter**? Its function is to [convert a scalar value to an Integer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#int). Its code is just:

```
public function filter($value)
{
    return (int) ((string) $value);
}
```

Which transforms the value to a string. If your value is an empty string, it'll convert it to 0, the reason why afterwards, in the validator's execution process, the required is not working (it checks a 0).

It seems to me, because of the name `id` of your input, that you just want to force users to enter something that must be a numeric. You can do it this way:

```
    $inputFilter->add( $factory->createInput( array(
        'name'      => 'id',
        'required'  => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array( 'name' => 'Digits' ),
        )
    ) );
```

Comment: I use Digits with pattern attribut 'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'pattern'  => '[1-9]*',
                'id'=>'prix',          
            ),

Comment: Those attributes doesn't have any effect. The allowed options are [these](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/AbstractValidator.php#L45). The `Digits` **validator** ends up calling the `Digits` **filter**, which works with [these](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Filter/Digits.php#L36) three fixed patterns (yours will never be used). All of them accepts the 0 value of your input (generated by the `Int` **filter** from an empty string).